# SplitBy with exponents

Tags: list-manipulation

I have

```
SplitBy[Flatten@ Join[{1, 2^n}, Drop[List @@@ 
Expand[Evaluate[(((FindSequenceFunction[ With[{nn = #}, (Rest@(List @@ 
Series[Nest[# + Log[#] &, x, #], {x, 1, 10}] & /@ Range[0, 10]))
[[All, 3, nn + 1]]]] & /@ Range[0, 4] /. # -> n)[[All, 1]]))]], 
2]], #*2^(_Integer + # n) &]

(*
{{1}, {2^n}, {2^(-2 + n)}, {-2^(-2 + 2 n)}, {2^(-2 + n)/9}, 
{-2^(-3 + 2 n)}, {7/9 2^(-3 + 3 n)}, {2^(-5 + n)/21}, 
{-(17/9) 2^(-6 + 2 n)}, {7/3 2^(-5 + 3 n)}, {-(181/63) 2^(-6 + 4 n)}}
*)
```

but I wopuld like the reult to be

```
(*
{{1}, {2^n, 2^(-2 + n), 2^(-2 + n)/9}, {-2^(-2 + 2 n), -2^(-3 + 2 n),   
-(17/9) 2^(-6 + 2 n)}, {7/9 2^(-3 + 3 n), 7/3 2^(-5 + 3 n)},
{-(181/63) 2^(-6 + 4 n)}, {2^(-5 + n)/21}}
*)
```

where the results are sorted by `#*2^(Integer+# n)`, but clearly there is a problem with my `SplitBy`.

Comment: So what do you really have problems with, `SplitBy[]`, or `SortBy[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. ah yes, `SplitBy`

Comment: Well, in any event, `SplitBy[]` requires a two-argument test function that tests when two things are the "same", for some definition of "same" for grouping. How do you say that two of your objects are the same?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I would like to group, for example, `{2^(n), 2^(n-4), 2^(n-5)}` separately to `{2^(2n), 2^(2n-4), 2^(2n-5)}` (basically by multiple of `n` exponent + some random integer).

Comment: Try `Coefficient[PowerExpand[Log2[#]], n] &` as the second argument of `SplitBy[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. great! It works! thank you! Please feel free to write up as answer for the accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer the following function with the caveat that I have not tested it on a computer with *Mathematica*. That being said, `SplitBy[]` expects a function that is applied to the elements of a list that, within a group, should give the same result.

On a hunch, I went with `Coefficient[PowerExpand[Log2[#]], n] &`; `Log2[]` is supposed to isolate only the exponent, but it can only do that after an application of `PowerExpand[]`. Having isolated the exponent, we then use `Coefficient[]` to look at the number multiplying `n`.

Comment: I used `SplitBy[SortBy[...,condition &],condition &]`, but I don't know whether this was necessary.

Comment: That would work; sort them by their exponents before grouping. Doesn't the original list have the things ordered by their exponents already?

Comment: Not if I dont use `Plus@@`  ...list.